# MySql : pivot from one table

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have this select

`SELECT concat(date_format(startLesson,  '%H:%i'), ' - ', date_format(endLesson, '%H:%i')) AS 'CALENDAR',
case when classroom = 'third_a' 
THEN 
(select concat(surname, '\r\n', about, '\r\n', tcode, '\r\n', book))
END AS 'THIRD_A',
case when classroom = 'THIRD_B'
THEN
(select concat(surname, '\r\n', about, '\r\n', tcode, '\r\n', book))
END AS 'THIRD_B'
FROM test_calendar
WHERE date(startLesson) = '2017-02-24'`

That produce this output:

```
CALENDAR---------------->THIRD_A--------------->THIRD_B
08:00 - 09:00---------->PIPPO(bla)------------>NULL
09:00 - 10:00---------->PLUTO(bla)------------>NULL
09:00 - 10:00---------->NULL------------------->PAPERINO
```

I need to show data as:

```
CALENDAR---------------->THIRD_A--------------->THIRD_B
08:00 - 09:00---------->PIPPO(bla)------------>NULL
09:00 - 10:00---------->PLUTO(bla)------------>PAPERINO
```

The table structure is:

```
id (int, pk)
classRoom_id (int)
lesson_id (int)
startLesson datetime
endLesson datetime
about varchar
tcode varchar
book varchar
surname
```

Any hint ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3):

You seem to need a `group by`:

```
SELECT concat(date_format(startLesson,  '%H:%i'), ' - ',  
              date_format(endLesson, '%H:%i')) AS CALENDAR,
       group_concat(case when classroom = 'third_a' 
                         then concat(surname, '\r\n', about, '\r\n', tcode, '\r\n', book))
                    end) as THIRD_A,
       group_concat(case when classroom = 'THIRD_B'
                         then concat(surname, '\r\n', about, '\r\n', tcode, '\r\n', book))
                    end) as THIRD_B
FROM test_calendar
WHERE date(startLesson) = '2017-02-24'
GROUP BY Calendar;
```

Notes:

- If you want one row per group, then use `group by`.
- There is no need for a subselect with no `from` clause.
- This uses `group_concat()` in case there are multiple matches.  For the data in your question, `max()` is probably fine.
- Embedding new line characters in columns is generally discouraged.

Comment: Works fine, thank you . About embedding the new line in columns, why is discouraged ? Thanks again.

Comment: @user1291822 . . . A SQL result set consists of rows in columns.  Having a row span multiple lines can be confusing.  Of course, you might have a good reason for including newlines.  I'm just saying that in general "row" and "line" are often synonymous.